# Animation of a spring pendulum

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics, animation

I would like to animate a spring pendulum. Below is my piece of code. The Lagrangian and equations are correct, in which I am sure, but the animation looks terrible and non-realistic.

Could someone help me with plotting the solution of my system of ODEs? Did I make a mistake in replacing the generalised coordinates to the Cartesian ones?

```
Clear[s, ϕ, t];
sol = First[
   NDSolve[{4 s''[t] + s[t]/2 + 9.81*Sin[ϕ[t]] - 
       2 (1 + s[t]) ϕ'[t]^2 == 0, 
     2 ϕ''[t] (1 + s[t])^2 + 4 ϕ'[t] (1 + s[t]) s'[t] + 
       9.81 (1 + s[t]) Cos[ϕ[t]] == 0, 
     s[0] == 1/5, ϕ[0] == 1, 
     s'[0] == 0, ϕ'[0] == 0}, {s, ϕ}, {t, 10}]];

x[t_] := Evaluate[(1 + s[t]) Cos[-ϕ[t]] /. sol]
y[t_] := Evaluate[-(1 + s[t]) Sin[-ϕ[t]] /. sol]

frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Gray, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}}], 
     Darker[Blue], Disk[{0, 0}, .1], Darker[Red], 
     Disk[{x[t], y[t]}, .1], Disk[{x[t], y[t]}, .1]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}], {t, 0, 10, .1}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

Comment: I am not sure that your equations are correct. Please show us the Laplacian and the constants used like mass and force constant.

Comment: @DanielHuber my Lagrangian is as follows: $$m(\dot{s}^2+(l+s)^2\dot{\varphi}^2)/2+mg(l+s)\cos\varphi-ks^2/2$$

and I've taken the mass equal to 2 and $l=1, k=1/2$

Comment: @DanielHuber and after re-checking I've got these ODE's:

$$m\ddot{\varphi}(l+s)^2+2m\dot{\varphi}(l+s)\dot{s}+mg(l+s)\sin\varphi=0$$
$$m\ddot{s}-m(l+s)\dot{\varphi}-mg\cos\varphi+ks=0$$

But id doesn't work either

Answer (score 7):

Here is the corrected code:

```
m = 2; l = 1; k = 1/2; g = 9.81;
la = m (s'[t]^2 + (l + s[t])^2 ph'[t]^2)/2 + 
  m g (l - s[t]) Cos[ph[t]] - k s[t]^2/2
eq1 = D[D[la, s'[t]], t] - D[la, s[t]] == 0;
eq2 = D[D[la, ph'[t]], t] - D[la, ph[t]] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, s[0] == 1/5, ph[0] == 1, s'[0] == 0, 
    ph'[0] == 0}, {s, ph}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]
```

;

The length and phi:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{ s[t], ph[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

x and y:

```
x[t_] := (1 + s[t]) Sin[ph[t]] /. sol
y[t_] := -(1 + s[t]) Cos[ph[t]] /. sol
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

And a manipulate to play with:

```
d = 1.1;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {x[t], y[t]}}], Disk[{x[t], y[t]}, 0.05]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-d, d}, {-d, 0}}]
 , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

There is actually still an error that I did not notice. In the potential energy `m g (l - s[t]) Cos[ph[t]]` the sign of `s[t]` should be positive. But then it turns out tat the force constant is so small, that the pendulum get stretched very much.

To get a more realistic result, where you see interaction between angular and length motions,, I increase the force constant by 50:

```
m = 2; l = 1; k = 50 1/2; g = 9.81; tmax = 10;
la = m (s'[t]^2 + (l + s[t])^2 ph'[t]^2)/2 + 
  m g (l + s[t]) Cos[ph[t]] - k s[t]^2/2
eq1 = D[D[la, s'[t]], t] - D[la, s[t]] == 0;
eq2 = D[D[la, ph'[t]], t] - D[la, ph[t]] == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, s[0] == 1/5, ph[0] == 1, s'[0] == 0, 
     ph'[0] == 0}, {s, ph}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], ph[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
x[t_] := (l + s[t]) Sin[ph[t]] /. sol
y[t_] := -(l + s[t]) Cos[ph[t]] /. sol
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
d = 3;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {x[t], y[t]}}], Disk[{x[t], y[t]}, 0.05]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-d, 0}}], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate your labour and cooperation!

Comment: In this case you should upvote (clicking the upper triangle) and/or accept (clicking the checkmark) the answer.

Comment: @DanialHuber Nice answer. Shouldn't the potential energy be `-m g(l+s)Cos[ph]+1/2 k s^2` ?

Comment: It depends on the direction of the  y axis.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann  Due to your comment I had a second look at the code and noticed an additional bug in the original code that I overlocked. Look at the addendum.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for the correction. Now it looks more realistic. I played around to simulate so called beat phenomenon  setting `k/m~g/l` but still didn't succeed. Any idea?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann The beat consists in the energy flow between the 2 coupled modes of angular and stretching motion.  As the coupling is pretty strong in this example, the energy changes fast from angular to stretching motion. An easier example to show beat, are 2 pendulum, coupled by a spring. Then the coupling strength is given by the spring constant, that can be adapted. For  weak coupling, it takes a long time for the energy to flow from one mode to the other.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you very much for your helpful answer. That's exactly the system i was thinking of. I was hoping to be able to simply transfer this to the elastic pendulum. My simulation show some "beat" but not decouspling of `s[t]`and `ph[t]`